# What alternate propellants could be used for firearms?

Tags: hard-science, firearms

What propellants could be used to increase the damage or injury caused by firearms?

Answers may include propellants that decrease the service life of the weapon (the weapon should be able to fire a minimum of perhaps 100 times with the alternate propellant), increase maintenance (including the replacement of parts -- after perhaps 100 shots), or make the use of the weapon more troublesome (brighter muzzle flash, increased smoke).

The ability to fire the weapon 100 times is arbitrary and does not need to be justified in the response.

Answers may include chemicals or materials currently available or likely available in the next 25 years.

The cost of the propellant or the cost of the bullet should not limit answers (for example if cut diamonds would increase velocity, include cut diamonds).

Comment: If answers do not need equations, why are you using the hard science tag?

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. You're asking for an open ended list of alternatives plus any alternatives that could be available in the next 25 years.

Comment: *"What propellants could be used in firearms?"* All of them, no exceptions. The question is asking for an endless list.

Comment: @sphennings made question more specific.

Comment: @AlexP Corrected error in question asking for more efficient propellants.

Comment: When writing the original question I neglected one of my primary points. Increasing the damage of the firearm. Apologies.

Comment: @EnglishmanBob You're still asking for an open ended list. As a rule questions with many valid answers, such as any alternative propellant, are too broad for this site.

Comment: Modern firearms are designed with a particular type of ammunition, down to the shape of individual grains of powder. For example, substituting pistol/shotgun powder (where the individual designs are shaped to burn faster) for rifle powder when handloading has a well-documented tendency to blow the rifle up.  (Which will certainly increase the damage or injury to the firer.)  It is possible to manufacture or handload "hot" rounds that reduce firearm life, but that just requires a bit more powder per cartridge and a willingness to live dangerously, not exotic substances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that expands.  Compressed air is used in air guns, [guns based on steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_cannon) have been developed, though not very successfully.  Electricity also works if you count that as a "propellant".

Gunpowder is an redox mixture that can be made with primitive technology and is easy to ignite.  Many other such mixtures could be developed with different properties and availabilities.  More advanced explosives generally have more energy/g.

If you have any further requirements I am sure a more limited list could be produced.

Comment: A list would be appreciated!

Comment: Any list could include a large fraction of the chemicals known to man, and other things beside.  A reasnoble list could be produced if you have any limitations, such as "available in the middle ages" or something.

Comment: Question modified per suggestion.